# Delete part in stored procedure not working

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmptyStagingTableBySupplierNr]
    @suppliernumber NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- routine body goes here, e.g.
    -- SELECT 'Navicat for SQL Server'
    INSERT INTO proclog (description) 
    VALUES (@suppliernumber);

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[productassortment_staging] 
    WHERE [LieferantenNr] = @suppliernumber;

    INSERT INTO proclog (description) 
    VALUES ('test');
END
```

If I execute the stored procedure directly all parts (insert, delete) work fine.
But if I execute the stored procedure from a third party software - only the insert parts are working.

I simplified the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmptyStagingTableBySupplierNr]
    @suppliernumber NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- routine body goes here, e.g.
    -- SELECT 'Navicat for SQL Server'
    INSERT INTO proclog (description) 
    VALUES (@suppliernumber);

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[productassortment_staging] 
    WHERE [LieferantenNr] = '123';

    INSERT INTO proclog (description) 
    VALUES ('test');
END
```

The same result: it works, if I execute it directly, but from the third party software only the insert parts are working.

I have changed the used credentials to the admin account. No change - so 
a problem with insufficient rights could be excluded.

Any ideas how I can solve the problem?

Comment: anything in the Error Log?  EXEC sp_readerrorlog

Comment: Hello Rodney, 

there ist nothing in the log.

Comment: So what is this "third party software" and have you attempted to contact them for support? You can try tracing the connection to actually see what commands are being executed by this app.

Comment: As @SMor suggested you could try to see the statements being passed from your application to the MSSQL via profiler